# How to make Leaflet popups follow the position of the cursor?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

My popups are set to open on `mouseover`, and the icons on my map are very large. Right now, when the cursor travels over the icon, the popup remains static in the middle of the icon. Is it possible to have the popup travel with the cursor's movements while the cursor is inside the relevant icon?

I'm trying to achieve an effect like [this](https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/projects/london2012/results) example from the NYT, but with Leaflet and the markerCluster plugin.

Relevant code:

```js
var markers = L.markerClusterGroup( {
....

    iconCreateFunction: function (cluster) {

        cluster.bindPopup(stateBlurb, {offset: new L.Point(0, -15)});
       
        cluster.on('mouseover', function (e) {
            this.openPopup();
        });

        cluster.on('click', function (e) {
            this.openPopup();
        });

        cluster.on('clickout', function (e) {
            this.closePopup();
        });

        return L.divIcon({ 
          html: '<div><span>' + stateName + '</span></div>', 
          className: `cluster ${classNameSize} ${classNameColor}`,  
          iconSize: null,
        });

    },

});
```

Comment: I don't know how to edit my question, but this is the correct link to the NYT map I'm trying to emulate: https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/projects/london2012/results

Comment: You can [always edit your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), you just left a bit of garbage in the same line as the URL. BTW, next time try to frame your question so that it [doesn't have a yes-or-no answer](https://jdebp.eu/FGA/questions-with-yes-or-no-answers.html).

Answer (score 1):

There are a few approaches to this; one of them would be to rely on [the `openPopup(latlng)` method](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#layer-openpopup) together with the `latlng` property of [Leaflet-decorated mouse events](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#mouseevent) and the `mousemove` event, e.g.:

```
var circle = L.circleMarker([0,0], {radius: 200}).addTo(map);
circle.bindPopup('Hello circle');

circle.on('mouseover', function(ev){ circle.openPopup(ev.latlng); });
circle.on('mousemove', function(ev){ circle.openPopup(ev.latlng); });
circle.on('mouseout', function(){ circle.closePopup(); });
```

This has the disadvantage that, if/when the user moves the pointer to over the popup itself, that fires a `mouseout` event, effectively flickering the popup. This can be worked around by leveraging [the `pointer-events` CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events), e.g.:

```
/* JS */
circle.bindPopup('Hello circle', {className: 'popup-with-no-events'});

/* CSS */
.popup-with-no-events {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

See a [working example](https://plnkr.co/edit/pyURDEmaXV2kkGfS).

Comment: Thank you - your example is exactly what I'm trying to achieve, but I haven't been able to get it to work on my end. I think the problem may be because the popup binds to the cluster, while the icon is a divIcon, which is how iconCreateFunction is set up in markerCluster. I can't bind the popups to the divIcon, and the popup doesn't move when it's bound to the cluster. I'll keep trying...